# How to display geometry datafield as Text

Tags: delphi

I'm using DELPHI with ADO and SQL Server 2014.

In our database table there is a spatial column for geometrical data.  We can read and write data to this field (more info is here :  https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server).

If I display this table using a TDBGRID component I got only (BLOB) shown for the content of this column in my table.

Now I want to see the content of this column. Is the any good coding to show the content of this column e.g. in a dbmemo as text.

The only solution I know is to read the field as text into a string and put this to a normal memo, I'm looking forward to get a more efficient method to access this data

Comment: You can use some of the [provided geospatial functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/create-construct-and-query-geometry-instances#returning).

Comment: how to apply this hint - if  i only have a Tdataset  from a query in my form

Comment: By writing a SQL command like `SELECT MyColumn.STAsText() FROM MyTable`.

Comment: but this means   get a record from the table,  run SQL query by some parameter , get result and put format text to a memo field, - i need to react on any change on  my db navigator ....   idea -> can i use a dbmemo field, link to a table  to be more flexible

Comment: I don't understand. So you're using `TADOTable`? And I'm not sure here, but SQL Server IMHO returns binary data as they are stored in the table.

Comment: I tried this wo success :      memo_geometry.Lines.Add(
      Fdatasource.DataSet.FieldByName('GeometryField').AsString );

Comment: You missed my point. That field is binary, it cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query e.g. for [**Well-known text**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format by using SQL function like [**STAsText**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stastext-geometry-data-type):

```sql
SELECT MyColumn.STAsText() FROM MyTable
```

An alternative would be fetching your data in [**Well-known binary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) data stream with parsing it on the client side to represent as text by yourself (the format is described). For fetching such stream you'd use [**STAsBinary**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stasbinary-geometry-data-type) function:

```
SELECT MyColumn.STAsBinary() FROM MyTable
```

Yet another option would be fetching raw [**geometry**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql) data as they are stored in database (as you do right now) and parse it by yourself. The format is described in the [**[MS-SSCLRT]**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee320529.aspx) document. But if I were you I would better write parser for the WKB format and fetch data in WKB format because it's quite established universal format, whilst SQL Server internal formats may change frequently.

Answer (score 2):

In case your geometry includes Z and / or M values it is better to call **.ToString ()** method.

```
SELECT MyColumn.ToString ()  FROM MyTable
```

The output includes Z and M values in addition to X,Y Coordinates. The .STAsText() method returns only the X,Y coordinates of your shape.