# Build a query on the selected record , position of the dataset pointer

Tags: sql, delphi

to display  the content of a geometry/spatial field I made a small component. This component does it's job when I provide all the information to query the table correctly.

- tablename
- fieldname of the gemoetry field
- fieldname of a field to select the correct element by a query
- a connection to connect the query to the correct database on my server
- a datasource to display other elements of my table for reference

as my component should be similliar to all the other dbmemo, dbedit ...  VCL components, I do not want to share

- a) fieldname of a field to select the correct element by a query
  and if possible also remove from parameter transfer to my component
- b) the  connection

here come my current working solution and need help on a) and b)

```
unit Unit_DBmemoSpatial;


interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, DB, ADODB ;




type
  TDBmemoSpatial = class(TMemo)
  private

    { Private-Deklarationen }

    Fdatasource : Tdatasource ;

    FConnection : TADOConnection;

    FdataField : String;

    procedure Setdatasource(const Value: Tdatasource);

    procedure SetdataField(const Value: String);

     procedure AfterSCROLL(DataSet: TDataSet);

  protected
    { Protected-Deklarationen }

  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }

  published
    { Published-Deklarationen }


  property  Connection : TADOConnection  read   FConnection  write   FConnection ;

  property datasoure : Tdatasource  read  Fdatasource  write  Setdatasource ;

  property dataField : String read  FdataField  write  SetdataField ;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('TOOLS', [ TDBmemoSpatial]);
end;



{ TDBmemoSpatial }

procedure TDBmemoSpatial.AfterSCROLL(DataSet: TDataSet);
var   aQuery : TADOQuery ;
SQLSTR : String ;
RIndex  : Integer ;


begin

     ///  this will only work on my table , not for others !!!!!
     RIndex :=  Fdatasource.DataSet.FieldByName('MyrecordIndex').AsInteger;


     self.Lines.Clear;

     self.Lines.Add( 'DBCOMP' + TimetoStr(now) );

     aQuery :=  TADOQuery.Create(nil);
     try
       aQuery.Connection := FConnection;

       SQLSTR := 'SELECT ' +   FdataField+'.STAsText() FROM ' +  'MyTable'  + ' where MyrecordIndex=' + IntToStr(RIndex);

       aQuery.SQL.Add(SQLSTR);

       aQuery.Open;

        self.Lines.Add( 'record affected ' + IntToStr(aQuery.RecordCount) );

         self.Lines.Add( 'Text  ' + (aQuery.Fields[0].asString) );

     finally
      aQuery.Free;
     end;
end;

procedure TDBmemoSpatial.SetdataField(const Value: String);
begin
  FdataField := Value;
end;

procedure TDBmemoSpatial.Setdatasource(const Value: Tdatasource);
begin
  Fdatasource := Value;

  Fdatasource.DataSet.AfterScroll :=  AfterSCROLL;
end;

end.
```

the calling code for my component goes like this

```
dbmsptl1.Connection := FCon;

dbmsptl1.datasoure := Fdatasource;

dbmsptl1.dataField :='geometry_by_Fieldname';
```

Comment: Looks like a standard task for a Lookup Field: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Defining_a_Lookup_Field

Comment: no idea how to use loopup which this task - you 'll need to motivate the SQL server to send you the data in ascii format , by default you will get the contant of this filed as binary; see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432394/how-to-display-geometry-datafield-as-text